# What is the general form of the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, normalization

**Questions:**

1. What is the general form of the wave function, i.e. $\psi$ in Schrödinger's equation?
2. What is the general form of the integrated wave function, i.e. $\operatorname{Eq.}{\left(1\right)}$?$$
   \iiint \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\psi \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z}
   \, \tag{1}$$

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is.

Comment: We know that for a progressive wave.                y = Asin(wt-kx).So I want to know that is it also applicable for psi function ?means is    psi =Asin(wt-kx)?

Comment: You won't get anything of interest by integrating $\psi$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I edited your question under the interpretation that you wanted to know what $\psi$ actually looks like in more concrete terms.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the equation on a case-by-case basis to see what $\psi$ is. The probability density is $|\psi|^2$. Let's consider a few examples:

- The particle in a $1$-dimensional length-$L$ box $0\le x\le L$ has wavefunction $\psi=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which you can verify satisfies $\int_0^L\psi^2 dx=1$;
- The $1$-dimensional harmonic oscillator's Hamiltonian has eigenfunctions $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar})^{1/4}H_n(x\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}})\exp-\frac{m\omega x^2}{2\hbar}$, with $H_n$ a Hermite polynomial;
- See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom#Non-relativistic_wavefunction_and_energy) for a very different behaviour again in the case of $1$-electron atoms.

Comment: It will be better if u give an example of such case of which u r talking about.

Comment: @KaustavGuhaRoy I hope my edit satisfies you.